# Web API Serialization of MongoDB BsonValue throwing error

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, asp.net-web-api2, bson

I have a class that uses MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue as the type for some properties. I can't use anything more specific because I need the property to be able to hold several different types in order to achieve the flexibility required.

So far I have had no problems with this setup between MongoDB and my application, accept when I need to send these objects to the browser from a Web API WebMethod. In this case, the default JSON Serilization, which uses Json.NET behind the scenes, fails to serialize BsonValues to JSON. It gives this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonString' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'.
```

I think what is going on here is that Json.Net is trying to serialize every property but most of the properties of BsonValue throw exceptions as they expect the user to know what type the value is and only use the properties for its actual type (i.e. AsBoolean, AsString, etc).

After a lot of research, it seems like there are two possible fixes for this but I need some more specific info on how to implement them and which one I should use.

The first is making my own MediaTypeFormatter, which I am reluctant to do because we have a very large application and I want to have as little impact on the rest of it as possible, and the MediaTypeFormatter is a global setting. The second is making a JsonConverter that can handle the BsonValue type, but I have some questions about how to do this.

- First off, how do I hijack the behind the scenes serialization to use my custom JsonConverter ONLY for serializing BsonValues?
- Second, which method on BsonValue will give me the correct value and format to pass to the JsonWriter in the JsonConverter? I read that ToJson() doesn't necessarily output fully valid Json and the RawValue property is deprecated.

I already have a JsonConverter that I use for deserialization, so I will just enable it for serialization as well and implment the WriteJson method.

I am using the MongoDB C# Driver version 2.5.

The following is my JsonConverter:

```
    public class BsonValueConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {

        return (objectType == typeof(BsonValue) || objectType == typeof(BsonNull));

    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        BsonValue val = BsonValue.Create(reader.Value);
        return val;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        BsonValue val = value as BsonValue;
        writer.WriteRawValue(val.??? /*What goes here?*/);
    }


}
```

My Webmethod is this:

```
    [WebMethod(true)]
public List<DataPipeline.Model.ReportingSetDefinition> GetAllReportingSetDefinitions()
{
    if (!CompanyNameSpace.Web.CompanyPage.GetLoggedInUser().HasValue)
    {
        throw new Exception(Utilities.CompanyMessage.UNAUTH_ACCESS_NOT_LOGGED_IN);
    }

    List<DataPipeline.Model.ReportingSetDefinition> defList = (List<DataPipeline.Model.ReportingSetDefinition>)DataSetDefinitionRepository.GetReportingSetDefinitions(CompanyNameSpace.Web.CompanyPage.GetLoggedInCompany().Value);

    return defList; //this is where behind the scenes serialization to Json happens.
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** As requested by CodeFuller, here is the model class definition (as well as the class it derives from), and the nested objects that contain the BsonValue and an example of an object that causes the error:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class AbstractDataSetDefinition : IMongoDocumentModel
{
    [BsonId]
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    //The left most data feed, which must be the new data that is being processed. Other data sources are joined on this data feed.
    public string BaseFeed { get; set; }
    //The source system of the base feed.
    public string BaseSourceSystem { get; set; }
    //An array of DataFeedJoin objects can pull in data from other data feeds.
    public List<DataFeedJoin> Joins { get; set; }
    public abstract AbstractDataSet GenerateDataSet(RawData rd, Dictionary<int, RawData> rawDataComponents);
}

[Serializable]
public class ReportingSetDefinition : AbstractDataSetDefinition
{

    //The name of the DataSet that will be generated. This is a handle that
    //will be used to identify all DataSets generated by this DataSetDefinition.
    public string ReportingSetName { get; set; }
    public string ReportingSetFamily { get; set; }

    //Mapping of which fields and from which data feed will populate the various collections of a DataSet.
    public Dictionary<string, AbstractDataFieldDefinition> Dates { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, AbstractDataFieldDefinition> EmpHierarchy { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, AbstractDataFieldDefinition> ContactHierarchy { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, AbstractDataFieldDefinition> Attributes { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, AbstractDataFieldDefinition> DataFields { get; set; }
}
```

The actual BsonValue property is nested inside the ReportingSetDefinition inside one of the implementations of AbstractDataFieldDefinition. The relevant classes are below:

```
[Serializable]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(SimpleDataFieldDefinition), typeof(ComplexNumericDataFieldDefinition), typeof(ComplexStringDataFieldDefinition), typeof(ComplexDateDataFieldDefinition), typeof(ConditionalDataFieldDefinition))]
public abstract class AbstractDataFieldDefinition
{
    public abstract BsonValue GetFieldValue(Dictionary<int, RawData> RawDataComponents);
    public abstract Dictionary<string,string> GetDetails();

}
```

And finally:

```
[Serializable]
public class SimpleDataFieldDefinition : AbstractDataFieldDefinition
{
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public int? JoinID { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public string Field { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public BsonValue DefaultValue { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public bool? IsDate { get; set; }

    public SimpleDataFieldDefinition(){ }

    public SimpleDataFieldDefinition(BsonValue defValue, bool isDate)
    {
        DefaultValue = defValue;
        IsDate = isDate;
    }
}
```

Here is an example object in MongoDB that causes the error (I marked the values that are deserialized into BsonValue types in C#:

```
{
"_id" : "38_Test_DefaultValues",
"CompanyID" : 38,
"BaseFeed" : "TEST",
"BaseSourceSystem" : "Company",
"Joins" : [],
"ReportingSetName" : "Test_DefaultValues",
"ReportingSetFamily" : "Company",
"Dates" : {},
"EmpHierarchy" : {},
"ContactHierarchy" : {},
"Attributes" : {},
"DataFields" : {
    "String Value Test" : {
        "_t" : "SimpleDataFieldDefinition", 
        "DefaultValue" : "Hello", //This is a BsonValue in C# object
        "IsDate" : false
    },
    "Number Value Test" : {
        "_t" : "SimpleDataFieldDefinition",
        "DefaultValue" : NumberLong(100), //This is a BsonValue in C# object
        "IsDate" : false
    },
    "Date Value Test" : {
        "_t" : "SimpleDataFieldDefinition",
        "DefaultValue" : ISODate("2018-01-23T07:00:00.000Z"), //This is a BsonValue in C# object
        "IsDate" : true
    },
    "Boolean Value Test" : {
        "_t" : "SimpleDataFieldDefinition", 
        "DefaultValue" : true, //This is a BsonValue in C# object
        "IsDate" : false
    }
}
```

}

**EDIT:** I have solved my problem using a workaround, however I don't really consider it a solution to the actual problem. I simply manually serialized my object list and returned a string from the web method, then parsed the Json string in my javascript in the front end. This method causes no errors.

```
    [WebMethod(true)]
public string GetAllReportingSetDefinitions()
{
    if (!Company.Web.CompanyPage.GetLoggedInUser().HasValue)
    {
        throw new Exception(Utilities.CompanyMessgage.UNAUTH_ACCESS_NOT_LOGGED_IN);
    }

    //System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.RemoveAt(0);
    //System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new PipelineUI.Serialization.PipelineToJsonFormatter());

    List<DataPipeline.Model.ReportingSetDefinition> defList = (List<DataPipeline.Model.ReportingSetDefinition>)DataSetDefinitionRepository.GetReportingSetDefinitions(Company.Web.CompanyPage.GetLoggedInCompany().Value);

    //JsonConverter[] converters = { new AbstractDataFieldDefinitionConverter(), new BsonValueConverter() };
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(defList);

    //return defList;
    return json; 
}
```

And in my jsvascript I simply do JSON.Parse() on the return value. It's not ideal, but it works. If anyone can solve the original problem that would be great.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I've created simple model with `BsonValue` property and it's serialized correctly with Json.Net (tried version 6.0 and 11.0). Could you please extend your question with model class definition (`ReportingSetDefinition`) and example of the document that causes the error.

Comment: CodeFuller I added the requested information. It is a pretty complicated system so I apologize for the amount of code I had to post. Thank you.

Comment: @CodeFuller Also I should add that I too can serialize things correctly if I do it manually using Json.NET. My question is how can I do so using the WebMethod's behind the scenes serialization?

Comment: Seems like the problem is not with Json.Net serializer. Are you sure the response is formatted as JSON? Could you please update your answer with thrown exception with full stack trace?